# android studio do not render page with appbar_scrolling_view_behavior

Tags: view, scroll, behavior, appbar

I use android studio to create new project on api 21 with a blank activity as the start page.the content_main.xml file is not rendered.if i remove     `app:layout_behavior= "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.it works well.I don't know what's the problem .

Answer (score 0):

the blank activity is actually builded for api 23,that is why the content_main.xml is not rendered by android studio